# Node js .replace() is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string, replace

when I run this code in node js I get TypeError: filter_list.replace is not a function, I've tried using toString too but that doesn't seem to be helping, can anyone help?

```
var filter_list =["abcd","efgh"];
filter_list.join();
return filter_list.replace(/,/g, ' AND filter:');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`var filter_list = [ "abcd", "efgh" ]` means that `filter_list` is an `Array`. The `replace` property function only applies to `String`.

Your `Array.join()` call does not convert (mutate) an existing array `Array` instance into a `String` - instead it *returns* a new string with the joined content.

You will want this:

```
var filter_list = ["abcd","efgh"];
var filter_list_as_string = filter_list.join();
return filter_list_as_string.replace(/,/g, 'AND filter:');
```

Or more succinctly:

```
return ["abcd","efgh"].join().replace(/,/g, 'AND filter:');
```

I recommend you program for Node in TypeScript instead of JavaScript - as it will catch these typing issues for you.

Comment: Dai, you don't need replace

Answer (score 2):

You can use `toString()` also,

```js
var filter_list =["abcd","efgh"];
filter_list = filter_list.toString().replace(/,/g, ' AND filter:');
console.log(filter_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

[arr.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/join) return a string, it does not change the array itself.

```
var filter_list =["abcd","efgh"];
var str = filter_list.join();
return str.replace(/,/g, ' AND filter:');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use Array.join with argument.**

```js
var filter_list =["abcd","efgh"];
console.log(filter_list.join(' AND filter:'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `join` doesn't change the variable inplace, instead, it returns another modified variable, so your code should be:

```js
var filter_list =["abcd","efgh"];
filter_list = filter_list.join(); // assign the joined array back to the variable
console.log(filter_list.replace(/,/g, ' AND filter:'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`.join()` does not mutate the original object. The correct code should be:

```
var filter_list =["abcd","efgh"];
var joined_list = filter_list.join();
return joined_list.replace(/,/g, ' AND filter:');
```